# Possible to have, in SVG1.1, something similar to the outcome of vector-effect="non-scaling-stroke"

Tags: svg

Imagine we have a long list of instances (as an example, see just two such instances (`INSTANCE1` and `INSTANCE2`) below) which all depend on some pre-defined `#DEFINED_RECTANGLE_WHITE` which does not contain stroke information in its definition.

As you can see, some of the instances will be scaled (see e.g. `scale(1 2)`). I am wondering what would be the best way of now stroking all of these instances (all should have same stroke-width, I do **not** want the strokes to be wider in any dimension on the scaled objects).

```
<use id="INSTANCE1"
  xlink:href="#DEFINED_RECTANGLE_WHITE"
  transform="rotate(90, 1, 1) translate(10,-400) scale(1 2)">
</use>
<use id="INSTANCE2"
  xlink:href="#DEFINED_RECTANGLE_WHITE"
  transform="translate(10,140)">
</use>
```

How to do this without SVG1.2 features?

Comment: Would the stroke have different color parameters? [Here is an ugly hack](https://jsfiddle.net/q3orL18h/) using feMorphology in order to make some kind of stroke, but this is really not modular, and I don't think it is any better than simply redeclaring your shapes.

Comment: @Kaiido Wow, that's really interesting. That's a good answer! The `<g filter="url(#stroke)">` can go over the two (or more) instances.

Comment: Not sure, once again, if you have mutliple stroke styles, then you'd have to have multiple filters, and it won't work with shapes with non opaque fill.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you use a filter to create an outline effect? You would have to enclose your use elements in a group or another svg and apply the filter to that.

Also, the dilate operator can have undesired results, like the bevel effect in the last rotated rectangle.

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="200px" height="200px" viewBox="0 0 100 100">
  <defs>
    <rect id="rectangle" width="10" height="10" fill="rgb(200,220,120)"/>
    
    <filter id="outline">
      <feMorphology operator="dilate" radius="4" result="result1"/>
      <feFlood flood-color="rgb(51,51,51)" result="result2"/>
      <feComposite in="result2" in2="result1" operator="in" result="result3"/>
      <feComposite in="SourceGraphic" in2="result3"/>
    </filter>
  </defs>
  
  <g filter="url(#outline)">
    <use href="#rectangle" transform="translate(50,10) scale(4 1) rotate(90,1,1)"/>
    <use href="#rectangle" transform="translate(40,30)"/>
    <use href="#rectangle" transform="translate(20,50) scale(6 0.5)"/>
    <use href="#rectangle" transform="translate(60,70) rotate(45,1,1)"/>
  </g>
</svg>
```

edit : oh snap! @Kaiido posted exactly the same answer while I was writing mine. Sorry for stealing your thunder =(